How can I properly utilize seaborn with matplotlib
I get an error code file not found when i try to use "seaborn on jupyter notebook.
Here is my code
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.style.use("seaborn")

Error message
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\style\core.py:137, in use(style)
    136 try:
--> 137     style = _rc_params_in_file(style)
    138 except OSError as err:

I try to install seaborn module but keeps getting an error

Replace plt.style.use("seaborn") with sns.set_style("whitegrid") (or any other Seaborn style like "darkgrid", "white", etc.). This avoids the FileNotFoundError and applies Seaborn's style correctly.
